# Problem with PyQt5 signals emitted from other classes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-signals, qt-slot

In the example below I want to send a signal from A to Main and from B to Main. Receiving the signal from A is OK, but B does not work. The tricky part is that the "calculations" in B must be triggered from  A, not from Main. Will appreciate any help.

Main:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

from A import A
from B import B


class Main(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.a = A()
        self.b = B()
        self.a.msg.connect(self.show_message)
        self.b.msg.connect(self.show_message)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def show_message(self, text):
        print(text)

    def start(self):
        self.a.dojob()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Main()
    m.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

class A:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject
from B import B


class A(QObject):
    msg = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.b = B()

    def send_message(self):
        self.msg.emit("from A")

    def dojob(self):
        self.send_message()
        self.b.dojobB()
```

class B:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject


class B(QObject):
    msg = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()

    def send_message(self):
        self.msg.emit("from B")

    def dojobB(self):
        self.send_message()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are thinking that the object `b` created in Main is the same object `b` that is created in A but that is false, they are 2 different objects (you can execute `print(self.b)` in each and you'll see that you get different id).

So there are 2 possible solutions:

- Do not create an object `b` in A and pass the object `b` created in Main to class A through the constructor:

```
class Main(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.b = B()
        self.a = A(self.b)
        self.a.msg.connect(self.show_message)
        self.b.msg.connect(self.show_message)
```

```
class A(QObject):
    msg = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, b):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.b = b
```

- Or do not create a new object `b` in Main and connect the signal of the object `b` created in A

```
class Main(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.a = A()
        self.a.msg.connect(self.show_message)
        self.a.b.msg.connect(self.show_message)
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it has something to do with the fact that they are different objects, but didn't know how to solve it. I will stick to the second solution. Thanks again.